# Power BI - FILTER in DAX measure not working properly

Tags: powerbi, tablefilter

I am using **Filter** in Power BI to filter all rows of table containing a word in specific column. When i use hard coded string "elements" as in example below, the Filter works fine.

```
FilteredTabel = FILTER(
FeedbackNouns,FIND(
"elements",'FeedbackNouns'[FeedbackTokens],,0)
>0)
```

But when i replace the string with the measure, it does not work in the same way. Below is the code i am using.

```
FilteredTabel = FILTER(
FeedbackNouns,FIND(
[selected word],'FeedbackNouns'[FeedbackTokens],,0)
>0)
```

What am i doing wrong ? As the resulted table in both cases should be same, because **string** and **[selected word]** are same. (Yes, i have verified that [selected word] contains the same string).

Comment: Works like a charm in my sample code. Could you post some sample data?

Comment: I have two tables
Table-1  contains two columns word column and count column.

Table-2 contains extracted words from sentences in a single column separated by '|'

Comment: Could you upload a sample pbix?

Comment: [link to files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HZTjs-YgOusPfX3mQgQdtWg2rDzyZref)

Comment: @TJ_ did you got time to look at the files ?

Comment: Yes :) Strange behavior, indeed. Seems like it's the behavior of CALCULATETABLE. Searched a bit, but coudn't find an answer. I've focussed on the result: I've created an extra measure, to see if the [SelectedWord] is in the [Nouns] field. Then you can filter the table (or page) on WordCheck > 0, to see only the matching rows:
WordCheck = SUMX(FilteredTabel; IF(SEARCH( [Selected Word] ; FilteredTabel[Nouns] ; ; 0) > 1 ;1))
Is this the result you were looking for?

Comment: In addition: I've created the measure for the filtered table, but of course this can be the Comments table directly.

Comment: @TJ_ 
WordCheck was not working as expected, then i used the variable for holding the value of [selectedWord] and now it works fine. WordCheck= VAR selected = [Selected Word] RETURN SUMX(COMMENTS, IF(SEARCH( selected , COMMENTS[Nouns] , , 0) > 0 ,1,0)) But still I am unable to filter the Comments table, i am using following DAX query, can you point the problem with it ? Filtered Table = VAR selected = [Selected Word] RETURN FILTER(COMMENTS,IF(SEARCH(selected,COMMENTS[Nouns],,0),1,0))